# MongoDB query issue

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Hello I'm struggling with writing an aggregate query for my MongoDB database filled with countries.

```js
    {
    "name": "Hong Kong",
    "topLevelDomain": [".hk"],
    "alpha2Code": "HK",
    "alpha3Code": "HKG",
    "callingCodes": ["852"],
    "capital": "City of Victoria",
    "altSpellings": ["HK", "香港"],
    "region": "Asia",
    "subregion": "Eastern Asia",
    "population": 7324300,
    "latlng": [22.25, 114.16666666],
    "demonym": "Chinese",
    "area": 1104.0,
    "gini": 53.3,
    "timezones": ["UTC+08:00"],
    "borders": ["CHN"],
    "nativeName": "香港",
    "numericCode": "344",
    "currencies": [{
        "code": "HKD",
        "name": "Hong Kong dollar",
        "symbol": "$"
    }],
    "languages": [{
        "iso639_1": "en",
        "iso639_2": "eng",
        "name": "English",
        "nativeName": "English"
    }, {
        "iso639_1": "zh",
        "iso639_2": "zho",
        "name": "Chinese",
        "nativeName": "中文 (Zhōngwén)"
    }],
    "translations": {
        "de": "Hong Kong",
        "es": "Hong Kong",
        "fr": "Hong Kong",
        "ja": "香港",
        "it": "Hong Kong",
        "br": "Hong Kong",
        "pt": "Hong Kong",
        "nl": "Hongkong",
        "hr": "Hong Kong",
        "fa": "هنگ‌کنگ"
    },
    "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/hkg.svg",
    "regionalBlocs": [],
    "cioc": "HKG"
}
```

These are all the field of a single country in the database. I need to get all the countries where the region is "Africa" and where the people speak English. So languages need to contain "English" this example has English so you see what I mean.

Can somebody please help me out

Comment: Can we also have your current attempt? At stackoverflow we expect sufficient research effort when asking a question. The question seems like an elementary problem. We would be happy to help if you can point out the specific difficulty you faced in your current attempt.

Comment: MongoDB documentation is very good with examples, for you query you need i think something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SZONVnT319O), you could have found solution faster from documentation, it has the exact example there.

Comment: @Lars Why don't you edit the question to show your first try as ray suggests?   It helps everyone to understand how problems may be tackled incorrectly for a variety of reasons, and then outline a good solution.